# Polar equation of an ellipse in polar axis with pole not in origin

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need to find the polar equation for [this ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWvFx.jpg), using OA (which is parallel to the x-axis) as polar semiaxis.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do that than the way I've done it:

In the cartesian equation $\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{(y-2)^2}{9}=1$, I replaced $x$ with $r\cos\theta$ and $y$ with $r\sin\theta$, expanded the result and solved for $r$ using the quadratic formula, which ended up working, but was a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations are

$$x=4\cos (t ) $$
$$y=2+3\sin(t) $$

Comment: There were a couple of mistakes in my post that I've editted, so I believe the parametric equations are now $x=4\cos t$ and $y=2+3\sin t$, correct? Anyway, I attempted to solve the problem using $t=arccos(\frac{x}{3})$ and then doing $r^2=x^2+y^2$. Is this what you're hinting at?